# Table of contents causes fatal error

Tags: table-of-contents

When I attempt to include a table of contents in any file, it will not compile and I get a strange list of errors.  For example,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}



\section{Dummy section}

\end{document}
```

compiles with no trouble, while

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Dummy section}

\end{document}
```

gives five errors, beginning with

> Paragraph ended before \contentsline was complete 
>   You can't use '\lastskip' in vertical mode.

No output is produced.  Please help, and thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Have you tried removing the `.aux` file and compiling twice?

Comment: Yes.  To make the situation more bizarre, I have two identical copies of the same file.  One of which compiles perfectly well, the other one not at all.  When I remove the table of contents from the second, it also compiles perfectly well.

Comment: Sorry, and have you removed the `.toc` file as well?

Comment: This worked.  Can you explain to me why this error happened, and why that fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say exactly what happened, but obviously LaTeX got interrupted by something during one of your compilations. This caused some incomplete data written into `.aux` and/or `.toc` and/or `.lot`, `.lof`, ... file. It is difficult to say what exactly it was, but deleting these files should solve the problem.